# How to get threads to run one at a time?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I'm writing a lift controller and I currently have it working with two threads: one for the lift object and one for the person object. They both call a lift controller class that correctly orders their actions using wait/notify. I want to get it to work with multiple person threads and one lift thread. So I when a second person thread requests the lift, it should wait until the current person thread has reached a pausable point.

The problem is that the `notify()` method does not specify which thread is notified.. How do I overcome this so that notify only notifies the person thread that I am currently interleaving with the lift thread instead of notifying some random person thread that is in queue?

Thanks

Comment: check my answer and the executable example to see if it is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Every waiting thread could have a user defined priority. 1st Person waiting- 1, 2nd Person waiting- 2.

You can broadcast notify that wakes up all the waiting Person threads but then each woken up thread checks its own priority decrements its priority value by one. If its zero it starts processing else it waits again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use multiple [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) objects in a Queue(may probably along with its lock). This is what notify signals, but Object only have only one condition object, so you need to do it yourself. Check [monitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_%28synchronization%29) before you go.
2. Every single thread(expect the first one), goes to the queue and poll the head , and then await for that condition.
3. After the Person thread done, signal the next condition object(the next thread is waiting on this).

This example may help you:

```
public class LiftController {
    static LiftThread lift = new LiftThread();

    static ReentrantLock liftLock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    static Queue<Lock> q = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Lock>();

    static boolean isLiftisAvailable() {
        return lift.isAvailable();
    }

    static synchronized void ocupyLift() {
        lift.setAvailable(false);
    }

    static synchronized void releaseLift() {
        lift.setAvailable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        PersonThread person1 = new PersonThread("person1");
        PersonThread person2 = new PersonThread("person2");
        PersonThread person3 = new PersonThread("person3");
        PersonThread person4 = new PersonThread("person4");
        List<PersonThread> persons = Arrays.asList(person1, person2, person3,person4);
        lift.start();
        for (PersonThread person : persons) {
            person.start();
        }

    }

}

class PersonThread extends Thread {

    public PersonThread(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " begins");
        LiftController.liftLock.lock();
        System.out.println(this.getName() + " gets liftLock");
        Lock lockToWait = LiftController.q.poll();
        if(lockToWait!=null){
            System.out.println(this.getName() + " tring to get lockToWait of "+lockToWait);
            lockToWait.lock();
            System.out.println(this.getName() + " get lockToWait of "+lockToWait);
            Condition conditionToWait=lockToWait.newCondition();

            if(conditionToWait!=null){//not the first one   
                while (!LiftController.isLiftisAvailable()){
                    try {
                        System.out.println(this.getName()+" awaiting  = "+conditionToWait);
                        conditionToWait.await();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        try {
                System.out.println(this.getName() + " holds the lift===========");
                LiftController.q.add(new ReentrantLock());
                Lock lockToNofity=LiftController.q.peek();
                lockToNofity.lock();
                Condition conditionToNotify = LiftController.q.peek().newCondition();
                System.out.println(this.getName()+" next notify = "+conditionToNotify);
                System.out.println(this.getName() + " release the lift");
                LiftController.ocupyLift();
                LiftController.releaseLift();
                LiftController.liftLock.unlock();
                System.out.println(this.getName() + " liftLock.unlock");
                if(conditionToNotify!=null){
                    System.out.println(this.getName()+" signaling  "+conditionToNotify);
                    conditionToNotify.signal();
                    lockToNofity.unlock();

                }
        } 

        finally {
            if(lockToWait!=null)
                lockToWait.unlock();

            System.out.println(this.getName() + " finish");
        }

    }
}

class LiftThread extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean isAvailable = false;

    public synchronized boolean isAvailable() {
        return isAvailable;
    }

    public synchronized void setAvailable(boolean available) {
        isAvailable = available;
    }

    public void run() {
        int random = new Random().nextInt(3)+1;
        while (true)
            try {
    //          System.out.println("---------lift is doing his job-----------");
                Thread.sleep(random * 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

output:

```
person1 begins
person1 gets liftLock
person1 holds the lift===========
person3 begins
person4 begins
person2 begins
person1 next notify = java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@191c0b76
person1 release the lift
person1 liftLock.unlock
person1 signaling  java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@191c0b76
person3 gets liftLock
person1 finish
person3 tring to get lockToWait of java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@24cc0f9f[Locked by thread person1]
person3 get lockToWait of java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@24cc0f9f[Locked by thread person3]
person3 holds the lift===========
person3 next notify = java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@5115a298
person3 release the lift
person3 liftLock.unlock
person4 gets liftLock
person3 signaling  java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@5115a298
person4 tring to get lockToWait of java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@6365d2be[Locked by thread person3]
person3 finish
person4 get lockToWait of java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@6365d2be[Locked by thread person4]
person4 holds the lift===========
person4 next notify = java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@31eeeaed
person4 release the lift
person4 liftLock.unlock
person2 gets liftLock
person4 signaling  java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@31eeeaed
person2 tring to get lockToWait of java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@3c818737[Locked by thread person4]
person4 finish
person2 get lockToWait of java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock@3c818737[Locked by thread person2]
person2 holds the lift===========
person2 next notify = java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@5bd44ae9
person2 release the lift
person2 liftLock.unlock
person2 signaling  java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@5bd44ae9
person2 finish
```